# Mqtt Pub-Sub with Quality of Service=2 in java

Tags: java, network-programming, zeromq, mqtt

I have some doubts regarding QoS=2 settings.

Mqtt publisher-subscriber am using Qos=2. Up to my knowledge by setting Qos=2 avoid duplication of message delivery among subscribers. In publisher i have set the Qos=2. I have two subscribers listening the same TOPIC. My code is running correctly but both subscribers getting the same message.

By setting Qos=2 Only one subscriber can get the message right?

How to solve this issue?

```
public class PubSync {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MqttClient client = new MqttClient(TCPAddress,MqttClient.generateClientId());
            MqttTopic topic = client.getTopic(MYTOPIC);
            MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(msg.getBytes());
            message.setQos(2);
            client.connect();

            MqttDeliveryToken token = topic.publish(message);
            token.waitForCompletion();

            client.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

QOS 2 means the that **each** subscriber will only receive **1** copy of any given message.

This differs from QOS 1 where it is possible that a subscriber may receive multiple copies of the same message as the broker ensures that message is delivered.

The QOS levels do not change in any way how many subscribers will see a message.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay...In my senario..using more than one subscriber listening on same topic,one among the subscriber can get the published message ...Just like push pull method in ZMQ. can u please suggest a option to solve this issue?

Comment: That is not how MQTT works, all subscribers to a topic will get the message, there is no way to have it only delivered to one of many subscribers. 

What you are describing is Message Queuing not Pub/Sub.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the MQTT messaging provider you are using, you should be able to share a subscription to a topic across multiple subscribers so that only one subscriber receives each message. In this case the messaging provider handles distributing the workload evently across all the subscribers.

This is known as shared subscriptions and you can read more about how it works in IBM's MessageSight product here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ism/v1r0m0/topic/com.ibm.ism.doc/Overview/ov30010.html

Comment: Shared subscriptions are not part of the (current) MQTT 3.x spec. Which means that each of the different brokers that support this style of access do it in a different way. It will be an optional component of MQTT 5.x which should mean that all implementations behave the same way.